# mp3 extractor for whole album mp3?

Tags: mp3

Some users upload a whole album as a single mp3 file. Is there a tool for Windows which can automatically create separate mp3 files from that file? I don't want to do this manually. I don't care what the mp3 file name is nor if it has missing tags and meta info.

Comment: "Some users upload a whole album as a single mp3 file." that sounds dodgy.

Comment: Not if he's "Tony_Henrich, Star Maker!(tm)" ;)

Comment: @Molly - there are artists that share their work, ya know ? We don't have to call the RIAA inquisition yet. And "the whole album as a single mp3 file" sounds like a live recording, at least that's the first that sprang to mind.

Comment: @Molly. Educate yourtself about Creative Commons, Albums on MySpace, home made albums, independent artists.. etc.

Answer (score 2):

There's a whole ton of those out there.  The problem with the 'automatic' ones is that they do 'silence checking' to determine when one song ends and the next begins.

Since lots of songs have 'silent' parts in them, you usually end up needing to manually check everything at the end anyway.

Having said that, the program I use for all my audio editing needs is [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/). It's free, open source, and cross platform.

It has silence checking in it, as well as other tools to help you split large MP3s into individual tracks.  Here's a [link to their Wiki article on the subject](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/index.php?title=Splitting_recordings_into_separate_tracks).  Plus all you'll need to fix what the 'automatic' things mess up. ;)

Comment: +1 Nice ideas. It'll be fairly straightforward (with Audacity or other) to rejoin the tracks which have silences.

Answer (score 2):

[mp3DirectCut](http://mpesch3.de1.cc/mp3dc.html).

If you have a `.cue` file that goes with the MP3 describing where the split points are, it'll use that. Otherwise you can pick the points by hand, or use ‘Pause detection’ to guess from where there's silence. (This isn't wholly reliable as there may not be silence between tracks, and there may be silent bits in the middle of a track; check it by manually listening first.)

The point of direct MP3 editors like mp3dc is that they won't re-encode the file. If you load, split and save in a traditional audio editor such as Audacity, you'll be decompressing and recompressing the data; because MP3 is a lossy format that would inevitably result in degraded audio quality.